# global variable is not global?

Tags: python, processing

this is meant to be a game of tic tac toe even though it is unfinished, the code below is my entire program, there are no other imports or anything like that, When I have top_left = turn it is meant to change the variable at the top called top_left to the value either 1 or 2, when the variable changes it is meant to draw an 0 for 1 in either the top left or top middle square for 2 your get an X in one of the squares, for some reason the value changes to one or two but the X or 0 does not draw

```
global top_left, top_middle, top_right
global middle_left, center, middle_right
global bottom_left, bottom_middle, bottom_right

#these are the variables used to check if someone has put their move their already
#0 = empty
#1 = Circle
#2  = X

top_left = 0
top_middle = 0
top_right = 0

middle_left = 0
center = 0
middle_right = 0

bottom_left = 0
bottom_middle = 0
bottom_right = 0


#code for changing turns
turn = 1
def turn_changer():
    global turn
    if turn == 1:
        turn = 2
    else:
        turn = 1

#board setup
def setup():

    size(600,600)

#this hurt my brain trying to fully understand
#lines dividing board
def draw():

    for y in range(3):
        for x in range(3):
            rect(200*x,200*y,200,200)
    #hope this is not what geomtry is like

    #top left ellipse
    if top_left == 1:
        ellipse(100,100,150,150)

    #top left X
    elif top_left == 2:
        line(0,0,200,200)
        line(200,0,0,200)

    #top middle ellipse
    if top_middle == 1:
        ellipse(300,100,150,150)

    #top middle  X
    elif top_middle == 2:
        line(200,0,400,200)
        line(400,0,200,200)

    #top right ellipse
    if top_right == 1:
        ellipse(500,100,150,150)

    #top right X
    elif top_right == 2:
        line(400,0,600,200)
        line(600,0,400,200)

    #middle left ellipse
    if middle_left == 1:
        ellipse(100,300,150,150)

    #middle left X
    elif middle_left == 2:
        line(0,200,200,400)
        line(200,200,0,400)

    #middle ellipse
    if center == 1:
        ellipse(300,300,150,150)

    #middle X
    elif center == 2:
        line(200,200,400,400)
        line(400,200,200,400)

    #middle right ellipse
    if middle_right == 1:
        ellipse(500,300,150,150)

    #middle right X
    elif middle_right == 2:
        line(400,200,600,400)
        line(600,200,400,400)

    #bottom left ellipse
    if bottom_left == 1:
        ellipse(100,500,150,150)

    #bottom left  X
    elif bottom_left == 2:
        line(0,400,200,600)
        line(200,400,0,600)

    #bottom middle ellipse
    if bottom_middle == 1:
        ellipse(300,500,150,150)

    #bottom middle X
    elif bottom_middle == 2:
        line(200,400,400,600)
        line(400,400,200,600)

    #bottom right ellipse
    if bottom_right == 1:
        ellipse (500,500,150,150)

    #bottom right X
    elif bottom_right == 2:
        line(400,400,600,600)
        line(600,400,400,600)

#dectects the quardnates where the mouse clicked and prints them
def mousePressed():
    println( (mouseX, mouseY) )

    #top left square hitbox
    if (mouseX > 0 and mouseX < 200) and (mouseY > 0 and mouseY < 200):
        top_left = turn
        turn_changer()
        print("top left")
        print(top_left)

    #top middle square hitbox 
    elif (mouseX > 200 and mouseX < 400) and (mouseY > 0 and mouseY < 200):     
        top_middle = turn
        turn_changer()

        print(top_middle)
        print("top middle")

    #top right square hitbox  
    elif (mouseX > 400 and mouseX < 600) and (mouseY > 0 and mouseY < 200):  
        turn_changer()
        print("top right")

    #middle left square hitbox
    elif (mouseX > 0  and mouseX < 200) and (mouseY > 200 and mouseY < 400):  
        turn_changer()
        print("middle left")

    #center square hitbox
    elif (mouseX > 200 and mouseX < 400) and (mouseY > 200 and mouseY < 400):  
        turn_changer()
        print("middle")  

    #middle right square hitbox
    elif (mouseX > 400 and mouseX < 600) and (mouseY > 200 and mouseY < 400):  
        turn_changer()
        print("middle right") 

    #bottom left square hitbox
    elif (mouseX > 0 and mouseX < 200) and (mouseY > 400 and mouseY < 600):  
        turn_changer()
        print("bottom left")

    #bottom middle square hitbox
    elif (mouseX > 200 and mouseX < 400) and (mouseY > 400 and mouseY < 600):  
        turn_changer()
        print("bottom middle")

    #bottom right square hitbox
    elif (mouseX > 400 and mouseX < 600) and (mouseY > 400 and mouseY < 600):  
        turn_changer()
        print("bottom right")
```

Comment: Please change the title to something that developers with the same kind of problem might google

Comment: Just changed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The [`global` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=global#grammar-token-global-stmt) is a declaration which holds for the entire current code block. It means that the listed identifiers are to be interpreted as globals.

That means, you have to put the `global` statement in the functions where you want to write to the variables in global namespace.

Move the global declarations to `mousePressed`:

```py
#dectects the quardnates where the mouse clicked and prints them
def mousePressed():
    global top_left, top_middle, top_right
    global middle_left, center, middle_right
    global bottom_left, bottom_middle, bottom_right

    println( (mouseX, mouseY) )

    #top left square hitbox
    if (mouseX > 0 and mouseX < 200) and (mouseY > 0 and mouseY < 200):
        top_left = turn
        turn_changer()
        print("top left")
        print(top_left)

    #top middle square hitbox 
    elif (mouseX > 200 and mouseX < 400) and (mouseY > 0 and mouseY < 200):     
        top_middle = turn
        turn_changer()

        print(top_middle)
        print("top middle")

    # [...]
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have defined a few functions, but you are not calling any of them. How should your program know which one to use when you run it ?

You need to call one or multiple of your functions. Try to add a call at the bottom of your program, and you should it "working". In quotes, because I will suspect you will have errors. For example, if you will call your function `mousePressed()`, then you will have an error complaining about `println` not being defined. Indeed, `println` is not a python function. Similarly, your program will not know about `rect()` or `ellipse()` or `line()` if you don't import them.

Hope this helps!